# Gnu make: Add a flag in a command for certain targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following `make` script (excerpt):

```
debug/abc-%.txt:
    python buildtxt.py --firstFlag <second flag>
```

where `<second flag>` should be `--debug` if `%` is `debug` and empty (i.e. no flag) otherwise. This behaviour could simply be implemented in `buildtxt.py` but I think doing it this way is more modular.

How can I easily implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `$(if $(filter debug,$*),--debug)`.

`$*` expands to the string that matched `%`. There's no built-in function to compare strings for equality, so we use `filter` for that.

Comment: That's quite insightful. I'm pretty new to makefiles and I think writing them is quite different than other scripts...

Comment: Is that `if` the shell's `if`?

Comment: @HerpDerpington Nah, it's built into Make. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions Every time Make sees a `$`, it tries to do something with it. If you want to forward it to the shell, it has to be escaped as `$$`.

Comment: Just to say: if you're thinking of makefiles like scripts you're already off on the wrong foot.  A makefile is not a script, like shell or python or whatever.  It's a _description_ of the _relationships_ between files involved in your build operation, annotated with some shell scripts describing how to implement those relationships.  make does not start at the first line of a makefile and start to "run" it, like a script.  It reads the entire makefile, constructs a graph of the relationships, then walks the graph to satisfy them.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm thinking of it more like a mixture of this relationship graph and a script. The recipes (scripts) tell makefile how to construct the files from their dependencies. The thing that confuses me the most are some parts of the documentation, because the do not seem to be easily accessible by google. I tried searching for something like `$(if <condition>, <true>, <false>)` as shown in the answer, but I only found it after I already had the answer... What kept showing up was `ifeq ...` but that didn't help...

Comment: Just go to the manual and use its index.  You can also view the entire manual on a single page and use your browser's search, or get it as a PDF and search that.  Start here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/  There are lots of terms out there which are hard to search for in Google, regardless of language.  One thing to be very careful about: the manual documents the latest release.  The older your release, the fewer new features it will have.  See the NEWS file for when things were added: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS